# Need to allow only two duplicate values in a column

Tags: sql

I am writing a query i am stuck with it.

Requirement is we need to allow only two duplicate values to be entered in DB

Example

```
Id   Name
1    Marry
2    Marry
3    Marry --> this entry should not be allowed only Id 1&2 should not be allowed to enter
4    John
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which dbms? (You'll probably need non ANSI SQL functionality here.)

Comment: and post what you've tried. SO is no code writing service.

Comment: That doesn't sound like the requirement makes much sense. What's the purpose of allowing one duplicate, but not multiple? Maybe you just want to add another field and create a unique index on top of the tuple? What are you trying to do? :)

Answer (score 0):

To select data with maximum of 2 duplicates in **SQL-Server** could be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    Id INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(60)
)
GO
INSERT INTO #Temp (Id, Name) VALUES (1, 'Marry'), (2, 'Marry'), (3, 'Marry'), (4, 'John')
GO
SELECT Id, Name 
FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Id) RN, *
        FROM #Temp  
        GROUP BY Name, Id
     ) x
WHERE RN < 3
ORDER BY Id
GO
DROP TABLE #Temp
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Id  Name
1   Marry
2   Marry
4   John
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0443d/3)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE INSERT
   ON your_table
DECLARE
  rowsCount NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO rowsCount
    FROM your_table
   WHERE NAME = NEW.NAME;

  IF rowsCount >= 2 THEN
    -- Stop action, depends on your DBMS. It can be exception or set NEW to be NULL or whatever you like.
  END IF;
END;
```